# Why I can't access component state in render in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

Trying to learn react.js I was trying to set the state of the component in `getInitialState` and access it in render using `this.state.myproperty` but seems I am doing something silly wrong .Here is what I have done so far.

**app.jsx**
this is my entry point

```
var React = require('react');
var App = require('./components/App');

React.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

**/components/App.jsx**

```
var React         = require('react');
var UserStore     = require('../stores/UserStore');
var ActionCreator = require('../actions/Actions');
var UserApp       = require('./UserApp');
var App = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
     users: React.PropTypes.array,
   },

 getInitialState: function() {
      ActionCreator.loadUsers();
      return UserStore.getState();
  },

  render: function(){
    var users = this.state.users;
     console.log(this.state);// see what is in the state
     console.log(users);  // see what is in users 
     return(
        <UserApp users = {users}/>
     );
  },
});


module.exports = App;
```

**Action creator**

```
var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatcher/AppDispatcher');
var Constants = require('../constants/Constants');
var ApiClient = require('../clients/ApiClient');
var ActionTypes = Constants.ActionTypes;
var Actions = {

  loadUsers: function(){
     ApiClient.getUsers(function(usersObj) {
       AppDispatcher.handleServerAction({actionType:ActionTypes.LOAD_USERS_SUCCESS, usersObj: usersObj});
     }.bind(this), function(error) {
      AppDispatcher.handleServerAction({actionType:ActionTypes.LOAD_USERS_FAIL, error: error});
     }.bind(this));
   },
};

module.exports = Actions;
```

Here is what I see in console

[image]

Why I can't access `users` from state or am I doing it in wrong way ?

Comment: I assume `loadUsers` is an async operation and at the time you are logging `users`, that operation hasn't finished yet. You are still seeing the result in `this.state` because the Chrome console is magical.

Comment: @FelixKling yes you are right .. so how can I load data from database initially for component from actioncreator? Please see edit I have posted code for actioncreator as well

Comment: You can also load the data first and pass it as props to the compnent, i.e. you are rendering the compnent in response to the Ajax repsonse. However, since it seems you are using flux, the store should emit an event when it changes, which your compnent listens to and then updates itself.

Answer (score 1):

On flux theory your component must call an action and wait for the store to notify the data is ready. It is the store the one which has to listen to the dispatcher.

If I were you I would return a mocked object in the getInitialState, subscribe my component to the UserStore change event and get the user data once the store tell me to.

And then I would update the component state(using setState method) at the UserStore subscription's callback. setState method will call render automatically.

Comment: Do you mean that I should set set addChangeListner() in component and emit change from store?

Comment: Exactly!! Here there is a great tutorial about that https://egghead.io/lessons/react-flux-stores