# Transpiling error in Typescript with React: Property does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, meteor, typescript

I am building an app with Meteor and React and Typescript is throwing me a transpiling error:

> Property 'gameId' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & {} & { children?: ReactNode; }

I have a component App which renders a component Game, as so:

```
render() {
    return (
       <div className="container">
          {this.state.gameId ? <Game gameId={this.state.gameId} /> : this.renderNewGameButtons()}
       </div>
    );
}
```

`Game` is an extension of `React.Component`, and is defined as below. As you can see, I have defined `gameId` as a prop in the `GameProps` interface. Why am I still receiving this error?

```
interface GameProps {
  game?: any,
  gameId?: string,
  subscriptionLoading?: boolean,
}

interface GameState {
    isAscending: boolean,
}

class Game extends React.Component<GameProps, GameState> {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isAscending: true,
    }
  }
  updateGame(game) {
    Meteor.call('games.update', this.props.gameId, game.history, game.xIsNext, game.stepNumber);
  }
  handleClick(i) {
    const history = this.props.game.history.slice(0, this.props.game.stepNumber+1);
    const current = history[history.length - 1];
    const squares = current.squares.slice();
    if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    squares[i] = this.props.game.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';

    this.props.game.history = history.concat([{
      squares: squares
    }]);

    this.props.game.xIsNext = !this.props.game.xIsNext;
    this.props.game.stepNumber = history.length;

    this.updateGame(this.props.game);
  }
  jumpTo(step) {
    this.props.game.stepNumber = step;
    this.props.game.xIsNext = (step % 2) ? false : true;

    this.updateGame(this.props.game);
  }

  resortMovesList() {
    this.setState({
      isAscending: !this.state.isAscending,
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.subscriptionLoading) {
      return <div>Game is loading.</div>
    };

    const history = this.props.game.history;
    const current = history[this.props.game.stepNumber];
    const winner = calculateWinner(current.squares);

    let status;
    if (winner) {
      status = "Winner: " + winner;
    } else {
      status = "Next player: " + (this.props.game.xIsNext? 'X' : 'O');
    }

    const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
      if (!this.state.isAscending) {
        move = history.length - move - 1;
      }
      const desc = move ?
        'Move #' + move :
        'Game start';
      return (
        <li key={move} className={move === this.props.game.stepNumber ? 'current-move' : ''}>
          <a href="#" onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</a>
        </li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board
            squares={current.squares}
            onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{status}</div>
          <ol>{moves}</ol>
          <button onClick={() => this.resortMovesList()}>
            {this.state.isAscending ? 'Sort Descending' : 'Sort Ascending'}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

let gameContainer: any;

export default gameContainer = createContainer(props => {
  const gamesSubscription = Meteor.subscribe('games');
  const subscriptionLoading = !gamesSubscription.ready();
  const game = Games.findOne(props.gameId);

  return {
    subscriptionLoading,
    game,
  };
}, Game);
```

Comment: See this - might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28660605/why-i-cant-access-component-state-in-render-in-reactjs

Comment: Are you sure that there is not any other `Game` component? Just verify your imports.

Comment: The code you posted is correct but incomplete. Filling in the rest correctly would result in working code. Post the rest of the code and we might be able to help.

Comment: @HardikModha Might these conflict?: 

`import Game from './Game';
import { Games } from '../api/games';`

Comment: @Aaron I've included the rest of the Game component.

Comment: @Gonzalo.- I am not sure what the connection is to that question as this is a synchronous operation, no?

Comment: Ah, `gameContainer` looks like the problem. Answer incoming...

Comment: @HardikModha It doesn't like that! On top of the original error I get:
`Type 'ComponentConstructor<{}>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<GameProps>'. `

`Type 'StatelessComponent<{}>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<GameProps>'. `

`Type 'StatelessComponent<{}>' provides no match for the signature 'new (props?: GameProps, context?: any): Component<GameProps, ComponentState>`

Comment: `React.StatelessComponent<GameProps>` ?

Comment: @HardikModha `Type 'ComponentConstructor<{}>' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<GameProps>'. Type 'ComponentClass<{}>' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<GameProps>'. Type 'ComponentClass<{}>' provides no match for the signature '(props: GameProps & { children? ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any>'`

Comment: @LondonBoy Please post where the `createContainer()` **type definition** comes from. Did you install them manually? Or did they come with the project? Or did you write them yourself? I can find no definition for `createContainer()` on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/meteor/index.d.ts).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the issue comes from your use of `gameContainer: any`. TS doesn't know what your module exports, certainly not a `Game` class, so you get an error trying to render it. I assume `createContainer` is a HOC, which is tricky to properly type but you can find examples out there, like [Redux `connect`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react-redux/index.d.ts#L49). Otherwise you could probably fix it using an assertion:

```
export default createContainer(
    // ... 
) as React.ComponentClass<GameProps>;
```

Or, if that doesn't work, try this:

```
export default createContainer(
    // ... 
) as any as typeof Game;
```

Comment: Tried this and it does eliminate the original error, but I get `'Type 'Game' is not generic'. `
I also tried 
`const gameContainer = createContainer<GameProps, GameState> (props => {`
which gives
`Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

Comment: Where does `createContainer` come from?

Comment: It is indeed an HOC. It allows React to import MongoDB data into props when using Meteor. [Description on the Meteor Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-createContainer)

Comment: Do you have a type definition for it? What does it look like?

Comment: @LondonBoy I don't see `createContainer()` in the [meteor types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/meteor/index.d.ts). Did you declare this function yourself or get a definition somewhere else?

Comment: @LondonBoy I updated my example. It should work, unless `createContainer`'s definition is incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues before, first verify the file type is .tsx. If that doesn't work. Check that you have saved your changes. In my case, I made lots of changes to several files and I did not save all the files I modified, the error went away when I saved all the files.